# DataGridViewAutoFilter, сохранить фильтры после апдейта Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, фильтры

Доброго времени суток,использую на столбцах фильтр с помощью DataGridViewAutoFilter, подскажите как сделать что бы после апдейта датагрида он не сбивался.

cn.Open();
                BindingSource bsshift = new BindingSource();
                DataSet dsshift = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtshift = new DataTable();

```
            dsshift.Tables.Add(dtshift);

            SqlDataAdapter dashift = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dashift = new SqlDataAdapter("запрос", cn);
            dashift.Fill(dtshift);
            bsshift.DataSource = dtshift;
            gridShift.DataSource = bsshift;
            cn.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < gridShift.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(gridShift.Rows[i].Cells["planned"].Value) == 1)
                    gridShift.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

                if (Convert.ToInt32(gridShift.Rows[i].Cells["ErrUpload"].Value) == 1)
                    gridShift.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
            }

            DataGridViewColumn truck = gridShift.Columns["truck"];
            truck.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(truck.HeaderCell);

            DataGridViewColumn firstCity = gridShift.Columns["firstCity"];
            firstCity.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(firstCity.HeaderCell
```